# How to format legend for dual axis plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code in R to make a slightly complex dual axis plot using `ggplot`. My plot is almost complete, however I'm having an issue with my legend. I've noticed that `ggplot` creates two seperate legends if one combines two different geoms into one chart - is there a way in which I can merge the two legends into one? Also, my second legend has two entries in it and I only need the first one (`Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)`), is there a way to remove the second `Overall Balance (N$ Million)`?

```
dat <- structure(list(Category = c("Overall Balance (N$ Million)", "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", 
"Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)", "Overall Balance (N$ Million)", 
"Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", "Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)", 
"Overall Balance (N$ Million)", "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", 
"Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)", "Overall Balance (N$ Million)", 
"Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", "Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)", 
"Overall Balance (N$ Million)", "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", 
"Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)", "Overall Balance (N$ Million)", 
"Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", "Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)", 
"Overall Balance (N$ Million)", "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", 
"Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)"), Year = c("2018/19", "2018/19", 
"2018/19", "2019/20", "2019/20", "2019/20", "2020/21", "2020/21", 
"2020/21", "2021/22 (est)", "2021/22 (est)", "2021/22 (est)", 
"2022/23 (proj)", "2022/23 (proj)", "2022/23 (proj)", "2023/24 (proj)", 
"2023/24 (proj)", "2023/24 (proj)", "2024/25 (proj)", "2024/25 (proj)", 
"2024/25 (proj)"), Value = c(-9226, -5.09893041491584, -3, -8918, 
-4.97862890962981, -3, -14197, -8.04324429255841, -3, -16138, 
-8.8, -3, -12658, -6.5, -3, -10418, -5, -3, -10281, -4.7, -3)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -21L))

library(tidyverse)

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = subset(dat, Category %in% c("Overall Balance (N$ Million)")),
           mapping = aes(x = Year, y = Value, fill = Category, col = Category),
           position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_line(data = subset(dat, Category == "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)"),
            mapping = aes(x = Year, y = (Value*1500), group = Category,color = Category), size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#7c3042','#6d1d26')) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#c7af76','#c7af76')) +
  theme_light() +
  labs(x = '') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-22000,3000,by = 5000),
                     name = 'Overall Balance (N$ Million)',sec.axis= sec_axis(~./1500, name="Overall Balance (% of GDP)", breaks = seq(-10,0, by = 2))) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is independent of the secondary y-axis. The issue is that in `geom_col()` you *map* the colour aesthetic, whereas this layer should not get an entry in the colour legend (just the fill legend only). You can fix it by defining the colour *outside* the `aes()` mapping of the layer.

```r
dat <- structure(list(Category = c("Overall Balance (N$ Million)", "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", 
                                   "Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)", "Overall Balance (N$ Million)", 
                                   "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", "Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)", 
                                   "Overall Balance (N$ Million)", "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", 
                                   "Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)", "Overall Balance (N$ Million)", 
                                   "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", "Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)", 
                                   "Overall Balance (N$ Million)", "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", 
                                   "Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)", "Overall Balance (N$ Million)", 
                                   "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", "Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)", 
                                   "Overall Balance (N$ Million)", "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)", 
                                   "Deficit Target (% of GDP, RHS)"), Year = c("2018/19", "2018/19", 
                                                                               "2018/19", "2019/20", "2019/20", "2019/20", "2020/21", "2020/21", 
                                                                               "2020/21", "2021/22 (est)", "2021/22 (est)", "2021/22 (est)", 
                                                                               "2022/23 (proj)", "2022/23 (proj)", "2022/23 (proj)", "2023/24 (proj)", 
                                                                               "2023/24 (proj)", "2023/24 (proj)", "2024/25 (proj)", "2024/25 (proj)", 
                                                                               "2024/25 (proj)"), Value = c(-9226, -5.09893041491584, -3, -8918, 
                                                                                                            -4.97862890962981, -3, -14197, -8.04324429255841, -3, -16138, 
                                                                                                            -8.8, -3, -12658, -6.5, -3, -10418, -5, -3, -10281, -4.7, -3)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                      "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -21L))

library(tidyverse)

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = subset(dat, Category %in% c("Overall Balance (N$ Million)")),
           mapping = aes(x = Year, y = Value, fill = Category),
           colour = "#c7af76",
           position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_line(data = subset(dat, Category == "Overall Balance (% of GDP, RHS)"),
            mapping = aes(x = Year, y = (Value*1500), group = Category,color = Category), size = 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#7c3042','#6d1d26')) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('#c7af76','#c7af76')) +
  theme_light() +
  labs(x = '') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-22000,3000,by = 5000),
                     name = 'Overall Balance (N$ Million)',sec.axis= sec_axis(~./1500, name="Overall Balance (% of GDP)", breaks = seq(-10,0, by = 2))) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Will look slightly better by setting `legend.margin = margin()` in theme (+1).

Comment: Agreed. Newline `\n` between 'Overall Balance' and the parenthesis would also work. Or give 'Overall Balance' as title to the top legend and keep the parentheses as label.